# Using React, how to acheive basic Accordion that has css transitioning toggle (from fullHeight to 0px) (allowing height to remain dynamic / auto)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

To transition the height from auto to 0 using just HTML, CSS had its own trials (css transitions do not work with auto values). I solved this using Javascript, by ...

Step 1. Setting CSS transtion for the content height

Step 2. Finding the actual height of the content (using javascript `content.style.offsetHeight`)

Step 3. Then setting the `content.style.height` to the absolute value (contents's fullHeight, instead of auto).

Step 4. Ensuring the browser registered this change by page by using forcing DOM reflow `content.clientWidth` for example forces page reflow)

Step 5. Then immedietely following, set the height to 0px. `content.style.height = 0` (which will transition start transition)

**The Problem**

However, now I'm trying to write the same sequence in React, within the onlick handler ...

Step 1 (I can do) - still use css transition set on the height

Step 2 (I can do) - using {refs} to get the `content.offsetHeight`.

Step 3 (I can “set” the height - **but** it won’t update synchronously) - using setState will asynchronously queue the elements height to be updated / rendered, but not before the crucial line in Step 5.

Step 4 - The element needs to have already changed its height value to the *absolute* initial value (set in Step 3) before the next Step 5. Thus this Step 4 represents something that would flush this change before next step.

Step 5 - would then change the height to the *absolute* final value (which would then trigger the transition - IF and ONLY IF the Step 3 had actually taken effect) (**Remember** css transition will only occur when elements value changes from an *absolute* value to another *absolute* (does not work on auto an value).

I wrote similar code using React (see below) but it does not work for obvious reasons (if you understand why the Code (without React) does work ... it requires instantly (**synchronously**) updating the height to absolute values (and also display property) at a couple of crucial moments in the same event handler, in order for the transition to work).

Because the necessary attempts to alter the height are stuck behind Reacts **asynchronous** abstraction, having to rely on setState to do things that need to be done immedietely (**synchronously**) before the next lines of code means I cannot get the transition to trigger (as my non-React version does).

---

Working Code (without using React) links:

JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mattlusty/rfdvbz16/6/

GitHub https://github.com/mattlusty/toggle-with-react.git

```
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  let content = document.querySelector(".content");
  let wasOpen = content.classList.contains("open");
  content.classList.toggle("open");
  // NB: STEP 1 was in the css (transition: height 0.3s)
  // STEP 2.1
  // ensures it is visible
  content.classList.add("block");

  // STEP 2.2
  // now can get the actual full auto height
  let fullHeight = content.offsetHeight;

  if (wasOpen) {
    // STEP 3
    // set initial height explicitly
    content.style.height = fullHeight + "px";
    // STEP 4
    // force reflow
    content.offsetWidth;
    // STEP 5
    // set final height explicitly - which it will transition to
    content.style.height = "0px";
    // STEP 6
    // after transition transitionEnd event handler resets height to auto
    // .. (and removes the forced display:block)
  } else {
    // (Similar steps as other part of IF block) ...
    // set initial height explicitly
    content.style.height = "0px";
    // force reflow
    content.offsetWidth;
    // set final height explicitly - which it will transition to
    content.style.height = fullHeight + "px";
  }
});

document
  .querySelector(".content")
  .addEventListener("transitionend", (event) => {
    event.target.classList.remove("block");
    event.target.style.height = null;
  });
```

---

Attempted / Not Working Code (using with React) links:

JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mattlusty/L21m0uyg/29

GitHub https://github.com/mattlusty/toggle-with-react.git

```
import "./app.css";
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    height: null,
    open: true,
    displayBlock: "",
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // to access the elements property offsetHeight in later lifecycle methods
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.myRef.current.addEventListener("transitionEnd", function () {
      this.setState({ displayBlock: "" });
      this.setState({ height: null });
    });
  }

  toggle = () => {
    let content = this.myRef.current;
    let wasOpen = this.state.open;
    this.setState({ open: !wasOpen });

    // STEP 2.1
    // This *would* set class to ensure display:block is set (to ensure it is visible)
    // ISSUE 1: however in React setState is asynchronous and this it won't be rendered in time to be useful for the next change a couple of lines later!
    this.setState({ displayBlock: true });

    // STEP 2.2
    // *would* now be able to get the actual full natural height
    //(ISSUE 1: in React the above change has not rendered in time for this to get what we need!)
    let fullHeight = content.offsetHeight;

    if (wasOpen) {
      // STEP 3
      // This *would* set initial height to the the required absolute height value (fullHeight)
      // ISSUE 2: Even if we had the fullHeight value from above  - setting it won't ...
      // ... take effect in time for the next steps
      this.setState({ height: fullHeight });

      // STEP 4
      // I *would* have now ensured the elements height updated immedietly, by using following line
      // ISSUE 3.1: but the above setState heights will not have updated the elements yet anyway
      // ... content.offsetWidth;

      // STEP 5
      // This *would* set final height to the the required absolute height value (0px)
      // ... and thus browser *would* detect the change triggering the transition
      // ISSUE 3.2: but the above setState heights will not have updated the elements yet anyway
      // ... thus when React renders the element - browser only sees change from height: auto to finalHeight
      // ... transitions dont work with auto values ... so no transition!
      this.setState({ height: "0px" });

      // STEP 6
      // ISSUE 4
      // If transition happens at this point (which is does not in React - because of the above issues)
      // ... transitionEnd event handler (above) would ...
      // 1) remove any explicit height so it returns to auto
      // ... this.setState({ height: null });
      // 2) remove class "block" which was only for ensuring visibilty whilst height is in transition ...
      // ... this.setState({ displayBlock: null });
    } else {
      // (Similar steps as other part of IF block) ...
      // *would* set initial height to the the required intial absolute height value (0px)
      this.setState({ height: "0px" });

      // the setState above has not changed the elements style yet ...
      // ... so the below wont trigger transition
      this.setState({ height: fullHeight });

      // If transition happens at this point (which is does not in React - because of the above issues)
      // ... transitionEnd event handler (above) would ...
      // 1) remove any explicit height so it returns to auto
      // ... this.setState({ height: null });
      // 2) remove class "block" which was only for ensuring visibilty whilst height is in transition ...
      // ... this.setState({ displayBlock: null });
    }
  };

  render() {
    let innerStyle = { height: this.state.height };
    let classes = `content ${this.state.displayBlock ? "block" : ""} ${
      this.state.open ? "open" : ""
    }`;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <button className="button" onClick={this.toggle}>
          Toggle
        </button>
        <div className={classes} style={innerStyle} ref={this.myRef}>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
          minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
          aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
          reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
          pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
          culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Your end goal is to create an effect of something that's a load-in transition from bottom to top or top to bottom? Kind og something like a transition component from material ui? Also you can just set the initial height of your component to be anything you want, no need to re-render the component to be an initial height. Components are susceptible to CSS like many other elements.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Martin. Re: the end goal - I have updated the post with full working Javascript version of code (with working JSFiddle). It seems like this should be a rather basic height transition function and I am reluctant to throw more libraries at the solution for something that I would have thought quite a basic function. Also - as you can see from the JSFiddle Javascript working example, I do need to set the initial height, then force this to be rendered before then setting the final height for the transition to occur (try deleting the line which forces the reflow / render).

Comment: You're overcomplicating things. Don't you just want the element to have a height of 0 in the beginning, then make a transition effect into another height?

Comment: I need the content height to be kept on auto to keep it dynamic to the size of its contents, (except when transitioning - as css transition requires explicit to and from values - not auto). So as and when it needs expanding (or collapsing) the height needs to only then be explicitly set to the initial height (0px if expanding / fullHeight if collapsing) and then set again to the final height (fullHeight if expanding / 0px if collapsing). Thus allowing the height to transition open / closed.

Comment: If your code works in general, then it'll also work in React. If you want something to happen on render, try the useEffect hook or if you're using a class component, use the componentDidMount method.

Comment: @Martin. (1st) Please understand my requirements - I need the height to (a) transition to and from its content's fullHeight to 0px (b) This fullHeight needs to be dynamic (ie auto most the time) as its contents are dynamic. (2nd) Please realise that css transitions DO NOT WORK with auto values (this is why I have to first change the intial height to an absolute value, and then again to the absolute final value). (3rd) If u accept last points, can you offer a simpler Javascript solution? (4th) The working Javascript does not simply work in React due to Reacts abstraction(see React code coments)

Comment: Have a useState hook that will hold and set the value of your initial height. Have a useEffect hook that will set the state of your useState hook that holds your initial height value on render. That way you'll have the height available. You can pair that with the non-react code that already works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Martin recommended (cheers buddy), I used useEffect hook (or the class equivalent method componentDidUpdate). This allowed me to render an initialHeight then immedietely hook back into the code after each render (update) any number of times to make subsequent updates as need.

So effectively toggling the height to and from 0px to auto in React.

---

This is first time I've really implemented Life Cycle methods (pretty much first React build altogether), so thanks for your patience @Martin.

If I've implemented it badly, let me know (it seems to do what it should).

Tried to make it as simple as possible, for the requirements, (crazy how many lines for a "simple" job you need) but if you think I've overcomplicated it anywhere, I would love to know / see a better way.

---

The JSX Code ...

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    open: true,
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({ open: !this.state.open });
    this.setState({ displayBlock: true });
    this.setState({ phase: 0 });
  };

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.phase > 2) {
      return;
    } else if (this.state.phase === 0) {
      this.setInitialHeight();
    } else if (this.state.phase === 1) {
      this.forcePageReflow();
    } else if (this.state.phase === 2) {
      this.setFinalHeight();
    }
    this.setState({ phase: ++this.state.phase });
  }

  setInitialHeight() {
    this.state.fullHeight = this.content.offsetHeight + "px";
    if (this.state.open) {
      this.setState({ height: "0px" });
    } else {
      this.setState({ height: this.state.fullHeight });
    }
  }

  forcePageReflow() {
    let x = this.content.offsetWidth;
  }

  setFinalHeight() {
    if (this.state.open) {
      this.setState({ height: this.state.fullHeight });
    } else {
      this.setState({ height: "0px" });
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let that = this;
    this.content = this.myRef.current;
    this.content.addEventListener("transitionend", function () {
      that.setState({ displayBlock: null });
      that.setState({ height: null });
    });
  }

  render() {
    let innerStyle = { height: this.state.height };
    let classes = `content ${this.state.displayBlock ? "block" : ""} ${
      this.state.open ? "open" : ""
    }`;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <button className="button" onClick={this.toggle}>
          Toggle
        </button>
        <div
          className={classes}
          style={{ height: this.state.height }}
          ref={this.myRef}
        >
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
          minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
          aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
          reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
          pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
          culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

The CSS ...

```
.content {
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
  transition: height 0.3s;
}

.open {
  display: block;
}

.block {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `ResizeObserver`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver

```
 componentDidMount() {
      let div = document.querySelector(id);  // <--- pass element id to observe
            this.resizeObserver.observe(div);
        }
    
  resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
            for (let entry of entries) {
                let width = entry.contentRect.width;
               this.setState({ width: width });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Mahi, however I'm unsure how the `ResizeObserver` is going to help set the elements height to an initial value (calculated fullHeight), then have the browser acknowledge this height, before then setting the height to the final value (0px). I have updated the post with my javascript code that does this (and included a working JSFiddle). Just need the equilant to work in React.

Comment: @matt I still don't know why you are overthinking it this much. Just toggle between a class that sets height auto and height 0px.

Comment: @martin If you tried that, you would be where I was weeks ago. Css transition does not work with auto value.

Answer (score -1):

```
      Collapse According Like Radio  - Once Open In Time
      You Can Add Multiple Rows
      React Js

         const Coll = (event) => {
         const Elem = Event.target;
         const Next = Elem.nextSibling;
         var Btn = Document.querySelectorAll(".is-active");
         [].forEach.call(btn, Function (el) {
      El.classList.remove("is-active");
      El.nextSibling.classList.remove("mrct-collapse");
    });
    Elem.classList.add("is-active");
    Next.classList.add("mrct-collapse");
   
  };


   css

   .mrct-collapse {
    Max-height: 83px !important ;
    Padding: 10px 0px !important ;
    }


  Html 
         <div ClassName="main">
                  <div
                    ClassName=" "
                
                   
                  >
                    <header  ClassName="collapse-header Is-active  btnRadio"  OnClick={coll}>
                          Login
                    </header>
                    <div
                      ClassName="collapse-content Mrct-collapse"
                      Style={{
                        MaxHeight: "0px",
                        Padding: "0px",
                      }}
                    >
                      <form
                      
                      >
                        <div ClassName="">
                        <p> Hello Word A </p>
                        </div>
                    
                      </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div
                    ClassName=""
                 
                   
                  >
                    <header ClassName="collapse-header BtnRadio"  OnClick={coll}>
                         login
                    </header>
                    <div
                      ClassName="collapse-content"
                      Style={{ MaxHeight: "0px", Padding: "0px" }}
                    >
                      <form  >
                        <div ClassName="">
                         <p> Hello Word B </p>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div
                    ClassName=""
                 
                    OnClick={coll}
                  >
                    <header ClassName="collapse-header  BtnRadio">ایمیل</header>
                    <div
                      ClassName="collapse-content"
                      Style={{ MaxHeight: "0px", Padding: "0px" }}
                    >
                      <form>
                        <div ClassName="">
                       <p> Hello Word C</p>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <button Type="submit" ClassName="">
                   login
                  </button>
                </div>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.